# Can I use a field name as AGAINST parameter

Tags: mysql, sql, full-text-search

Maybe is a bug on SqlFiddle **[Sql Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9155e2/7)**

```
SELECT `ID`, `Name1`, `Name2`,
       MATCH (`Name1`)  
       AGAINST ('Ministry Sound' IN BOOLEAN MODE) AS score 
FROM Table3
ORDER BY score DESC;
```

Generate this result:

```
| ID |             Name1 |          Name2 |               score |
|----|-------------------|----------------|---------------------|
|  1 | Ministry of Sound | Ministry Sound | 0.45528939366340637 |
|  2 |        4 Elements |  Four Elements |                   0 |
|  3 | Blue Marlin Ibiza |    Blue Marlin |                   0 |
```

But if I try use `Name2` instead of `'Ministry Sound'` so compare every row I get an error

> Incorrect arguments to AGAINST

Comment: the MySQL docs say clearly that the expression in `AGAINST` must be a constant string and can't be a column: `The search string must be a string value that is constant during query evaluation. This rules out, for example, a table column because that can differ for each row`

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/fulltext-search.html  = source

Comment: @Lamak You are right, google send me to `12.9.2` instead of `12.9` and there didnt say anything.